# Delay with slow fade in after rest of page is loaded - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein

Basically, what I want to do is make it so that a Div with an image fade in after a delay, after the rest of the page has loaded. So all of the page would load, then there would be a delay, then the image would fade in. Here is my code. It doesn't seem to be working.

```
    $(window).load(function() {  // $(document).ready shorthand
       $('.contentrightCopy').delay(i * 400).fadeIn(2000);
    });
```

Comment: What's not working about it? And why are you referencing an element with `.`?

Comment: When I test it, the image doesn't fade in or delay, so the function isn't working. the "." is referring to a Divtag with an image inside of it.

Comment: What happens is that when the rest of the page is loaded, the copyright div delays for 400 and then it fades in. It doesn't seem to work working, though.

Comment: @user2725423 - Off topic: `$(window).load` is not the shorthand of `$(document).ready`. Technically, they are not even the same. This, `$()`, *is* the shorthand.

Comment: $(window).load is when the document is loaded and $(document).ready is when the document itself has loaded.

Comment: what happens if you remove the delay? What if you remove the fade? What if you place it outside of your window load? We need you to narrow things down to figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: `i * 400` might crash it.

Comment: It still doesn't work if I do that.

Comment: Changed the value of 400 to 100, no change.

Comment: Maybe it can be coded in a different way?

Comment: Maybe, but, again, you need to give us more to go off of here.

Comment: Also, what is the value of 'i'?

Comment: Well, then why do you have it there?

Comment: Have you looked in your console for errors? I'm betting you're getting an undefined error for `i`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Works fine now.
I added...

```
    display: none;
```

To the CSS of the .contentrightCopy then added this javascript.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.contentrightCopy').delay(2000).fadeIn(2000)
})
```